# How to use flash and session in a view in Play Framework? [Scala]

Tags: playframework-2.3

I need to pass both a flash value and a session value into one view in Play Framework. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Both the session and the flash objects are accessible from the request. Simply pass request from a controller to a view. Usually it's done by an implicit parameter:

```
@()(implicit request: RequestHeader)

@request.session.get("yourSessionKey")
@request.flash.get("yourFlashKey")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@()(implicit flash : Flash, request: RequestHeader)
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
@if(request.session.get("example").toList(0) == example2){
<a href="#example>"><h5>example</h5></a>
}
```